# Using AOP in Grails is not working for service

Tags: spring, grails, aop

I use Grails 2.2.3 and type following codes in grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy

```
beans = {
    xmlns aop:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    loggerAspect(com.test.aop.aspect.LoggerAspect)
    aop{
        config("proxy-target-class": true) {
            aspect(id: "beforeService", ref: "loggerAspect") {
                before method: "beforeMethod", 
                pointcut: "execution(* com.test.DemoService.serviceMethod())"
            }
            aspect(id: "afterService", ref: "loggerAspect") {
                after method: "afterMethod", 
                pointcut: "execution(* com.test.DemoService.serviceMethod())"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then, create an aspect class under src/groovy/com/test/aop/aspect

```
package com.test.aop.aspect
class LoggerAspect {
    def beforeMethod(JoinPoint jp){
        println '-- Before Method.'
    }

    def afterMethod(JoinPoint jp){
        println '-- After Method.'
    }
}
```

And create a service class under grails-app/services/com/test

```
package com.test
class DemoService {
    def serviceMethod() {
        println 'In DemoService.serviceMethod()'
    }
}
```

And create a controller to call service for testing

```
package com.test
class DemoController {
    def index() {
        println 'In DemoController.index()'
        def demoService = new DemoService()
        demoService.serviceMethod()

         render 'Hello World'
    }
}
```

Finally, I test the aop through url:

```
http://myhost:8080/grails-spring-aop/demo/index
```

and the aop is not invoked. Following is the result:

```
| Server running. Browse to http://myhost:8080/grails-spring-aop/
In DemoController.index()
In DemoService.serviceMethod()
```

I add the following line to the service class:

```
static transactional = false
```

And, it's still not working for me.

Anyone an idea how this can be solved or is this not possible.
Or I do the something wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to inject the service (spring bean) in the controller instead of creating an instance of it.

```
package com.test
class DemoController {
    def demoService //Autowired, not required to specify in resources.groovy

    def index() {
        println 'In DemoController.index()'
        demoService.serviceMethod()

        render 'Hello World'
    }
}
```

Moreover, the aspect can be made annotation based as below:

```
package com.test.aop.aspect

@Aspect
class LoggerAspect {

    //A more generic advice would be as below
    //@Before("execution(* com.test.*.*(..))")
    @Before("com.test.DemoService.serviceMethod()")
    def beforeMethod(){
        println '-- Before Method.'
    }

    //A more generic advice would be as below
    //@Around("execution(* com.test.*.*(..))")
    @After("com.test.DemoService.serviceMethod()")
    def afterMethod(){
        println '-- After Method.'
    }
}
```

And resources.groovy could become:

```
beans = {
    loggerAspect(com.test.aop.aspect.LoggerAspect)

    xmlns aop:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    aop{
        config("proxy-target-class": true) {
            aspect(id: "loggerAspectService", ref: "loggerAspect") 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Thomas.Yu Unless you allow the spring container to resolve the dependency, the aspect will not be able to execute advice before, after or around a pointcut.

Comment: @Thomas.Yu Good the hear it works. I added some more information as to how the Aspect can be written annotation based so that bean dependencies can be minimized.