# How to implement AOP Profiling in Grails application

Tags: grails, spring-aop

I am trying to implement AOP in grails.
I followed this [link](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2012/09/25/how-to-implemnet-aop-profiling-in-grails-application/) .

I created a service and an advice class in src/groovy folder.
But unfortunately code is not working for me.below is my code.

```
package com.app.auth
Class MyDemoService
{
  void findAdviceTest(){
    println"find by is running"
  }
}
```

AOP code (MyNewAdvice.groovy file in src/groovy )

```
package com.app.auth;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Aspect
@Component
public class MyNewAdvice
{
  @Before("execution(* com.app.auth.MyDemoService.find*())")
  public void connectBeforeFind(){
    println "aop implemented"
  }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Can this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17667315/2051952) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is using the Component annotation.  Have you enabled the component scanner in resources.groovy with something like this?…

```
// grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy
beans = {
    xmlns context: 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context'
    context.'component-scan'( 'base-package' : 'com.app.auth' )
}
```

Comment: You also probably want com.app.auth.MyDemoService.find*() instead of grails.app.services.com.app.auth.MyDemoService.find*() in your selection expression.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff , it worked. but this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667046/using-aop-in-grails-is-not-working-for-service/17667315#17667315 given by dmahapatro is also working for me.Can you explain the basic difference b/w the two and which one is better?

Comment: @akash,

There is a lot going on and not know which parts you are already familiar with and which you aren't, it might be too much to get into in a StackOverflow comment.  The short of it is that Spring needs to know about your advice so it can applied to other beans.  You might also get away with something like this...

    // grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy
    beans = {
        myAdvice com.app.auth.MyNewAdvice
    }

With that you could remove the Component annotation from your advice.  Since you are explicitly registering the bean there, the component scanner is not needed.

HTH